# How to find out from where value is Being changed in ng-model?

Tags: angularjs

When i focus out from textbox value is being empty of my model and to check i have added debugger to all place from where value of model is being set but when value of model is being changed no debugger is being hit, so how can i find out the code from where my model value is being changed?

Answer (score 0):

you can use $watch to debug if the value is changed:

```
$scope.$watch('model.value', function (newValue) {
    ...
}, true);
```

[watch api](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

Comment: Even you add a breakpoint in this watch function, you still have no idea who changed the value or when it's changed, this watch function will be triggered in a digest loop.

Comment: Thanks @huan but this will give the new value but not the reference point or line no. or some thing like that by which i can find out from where my model's value is being changed.

Comment: no, it's wrong. The call stack can not help you out as this function is triggered by Angular's digest loop.

Comment: @NikhilGupta could you create a plnkr so we can help you look at the problem?

Comment: Thanks @huanfeng for reply , my problem has been resolved, there is  some code which is changing model's value, but there was confusion because Model's value was not reflecting suddenly on the UI when it is being changed in JS file, it was reflecting after focus out so the difference of time when model's value changed and reflect on the UI after sometime was creating so much confusion.